# Using sorted() to find the unique value in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of integers and I am trying to find the unique value of a list.  I can't use `count()` because it exceeds the time limit so I figured that using `sorted()` and see if the element `i` is not equal to `i+1`.

```
class Solution:
    
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        
        nums_sort = sorted(nums, reverse=True)
        value = 0
        
        for i in range(0, len(nums_sort)):
            if nums_sort[i] != nums_sort[i+1]:
                value = nums_sort[i]
        
        return value
```

However, this throws an `list index out of range` error.  I know why and that is because I am trying to access `nums_sort[i+1]` even when `i = len(nums_sort)`.  However, I don't know how to remedy this problem.

**Update**

This is what I changed my code to per recommendation:

```
class Solution:
    
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        
        nums_sort = sorted(nums, reverse=True)
        value = 0
        
        for i in range(0, len(nums_sort)-1):
            if nums_sort[i] != nums_sort[i+1]:
                value = nums_sort[i]
        
        return value
```

And now its just not computing it properly.

```
Your input  [2,2,1]
Output       2
Expected     1
```

Comment: If you know that you want to look one index further than ``i``, why don't you count for one index less? Are you aware of ``itertools.groupby``?

Comment: if `i` is the last number in `range`, `i+1` will take you past the end. You could use `len(nums) - 1`

Comment: What is `counted`? If you mean `collections.Counter`, I don't see how sorting and *then* walking through the list will be any faster.

Comment: @chepner `count()`

Comment: `itertools.count`? That just generates an infinite stream of integers starting with 0.

Comment: All you are doing is finding the last point in the list where the value changes; nothing you do checks if the value is unique or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finding a unique value, sorting will have a greater time complexity (`O(n log n)`) than a simple linear scan (`O(n)`).

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import List

def find_unique(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    c = Counter(nums)
    element, count = c.most_common()[-1]
    if count > 1:
        raise ValueError('All elements of nums appear more than once.')
    return element


numbers = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2]
print(find_unique(numbers))  # 3
```

EDIT: Thanks to @chepner for pointing out the existence of `Counter.most_common`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly walk the list: `n = c.most_common[-1]` is the single unique element if `c[n] == 1`.

Comment: Right looks like it would be `c.most_common[-1][0]` since each element is a tuple of the form `(element, count)`. Will update!

Comment: You still need to _call_ `most_common`, don't you?

Comment: Yes! Typo on my part it should be `c.most_common()[-1][0]`

Answer (score 0):

It throws a `list index out of range` exception because, you try to access list[i+1], when your loop gets to the last element, which is `i`.

Try

```
for i in range(0, len(nums_sort)-1):
```